# Make UICollectionView zoomable?

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview

Is there any method make the `UICollectionView` `zoomable`, i.e. when you pinch, all the cells can be zoomed in and out.
I can implement this in `UIScrollView` by returning the only `subview` of the `UIScrollView` from `delegate` method

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Since `UICollectionView` is kind of `UIScrollView`, is there a way or work around to implement this? Does the `UICollectionView` has one direct subview that contains all cells?
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think what you're asking for looks like what is done in the `WWDC1012` video entitled **[Advanced Collection Views and Building Custom Layouts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vB2TMS2uhE)** (demo starts at 20:20).

You basically have to add `pinchGesture` to you `UICollectionView`, then pass the `pinch properties` (scale, center) to the `UICollectionViewLayout` (which is a `subclass` of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`), your layout will then perform the `transformations` needed to `zoom` on the desired cell.

Comment: I tried taking this route, but the cell will disappear once it gets bigger than the collectionView

Comment: This happens to me as well. I have screen-sized UITableViewCells, and I can scale them down, but scaling them up makes them disappear.

Comment: You can override "collectionViewContentSize" to make it scale with the cell.

Comment: Here is the link to the video.  You have to log in.  [WWDC102 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/)  Then, look for the section labeled "Advanced Collection Views and Building Custom Layouts" like @stant said above

Comment: In the video, the section on adding pinch scaling starts at 20:20. Note – the technique as given shows how to add scaling to one cell in the collection view, rather than all cells, as requested by OP.

Comment: What if you are not using the flow layout but a custom implementation?

Comment: Well then it's up to you;), but you can clearly get inspiration from what is described in the video.

Comment: here's an example with code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406254/zoom-entire-uicollectionview