# zoom entire UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming, uicollectionview

I have an iPad App where I'm using a UICollectionView and each UICollectionViewCell contains just a single UIImage.
Currently I'm displaying per 9 UIImages (3 rows * 3 columns) per page, I have several pages.

I would like to use Pinch Gesture to zoom on the entire UICollectionView to increase/decrease the number of row/columns displayed per page and the best would be to have beautiful zoom animation during the Pinch gesture!

Currently, I have added a Pinch Gesture on my UICollectionView. I catch the Pinch Gesture event to compute the number of rows/columns using the scale factor, if it has changed then I update the full UICollectionView using:

```
[_theCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
     [_theCollectionView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
     [_theCollectionView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
 } completion:nil];
```

It works but I don't have smooth animation during the transition.

Any idea? UICollectionView inherits from UIScrollView, is there a possibility to re-use the UIScrollView Pinch gesture feature to reach my goal?

Answer (score 32):

I'm assuming you're using the default UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, right? Then make sure you respond accordingly to the delegate methods, and when the pinch gesture occurs, simply invalidate the layout.

For example, if I want to adjust the size of every item, while pinching:

```
@interface ViewController () <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@property (nonatomic,assign) CGFloat scale;
@property (nonatomic,weak)   IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scale = 1.0;

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didReceivePinchGesture:)];
    [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(50*self.scale, 50*self.scale);
}

- (void)didReceivePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    static CGFloat scaleStart;

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        scaleStart = self.scale;
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        self.scale = scaleStart * gesture.scale;
        [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    }
}
```

The property `self.scale` is just for show, you can apply this same concept to any other attribute, this doesn't require a beginUpdates/endUpdates because the user himself is carrying the timing of the scale.

[Here's a running project](https://github.com/CanTheAlmighty/SamplePinchGesture), in case you want to see it in action.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Checked your demo and its really useful. Can you guide on how we can show these transitions with a nice animation...I am a newbie to UICollectionView.

Comment: Great answer, curious if you have any insight on what to do if the layout is more 'fixed' and you want to zoom in / out and pan around (not move the items).  Think of a map for instance with items on the map being UICollectionCells and tiles potentially being reusableviews or similar.

Comment: @MobileVet For my thesis I wrote a custom UICollectionViewLayout that creates something like a map, and its entirely possible. If you make the content size that the collection view layout reports larger with a scale factor, then you can have both zooming and panning.

Comment: That inadvertently kind of makes the content much much bigger than it needs to be, right? :/

Comment: @fatuhoku well, yes. What's your concern?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my 2 cents question, I have found the solution, very simple.

In my `PinchGesture` callback I have just done the following:

```
void (^animateChangeWidth)() = ^() {
    _theFlowLayout.itemSize = cellSize;
};

[UIView transitionWithView:self.theCollectionView 
                  duration:0.1f 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
                animations:animateChangeWidth 
                completion:nil];
```

All cells of my `UICollectionView` are successfully changed and with a nice `transition`.

Comment: That's not the proper way to handle scaling, you're basically forcing a redraw of the whole collectionView, when that feature is already supported by layout invalidation `[collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]`. I left an answer with a more thorough explanation and example.

Comment: Please, can you add more details on this?

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin.iOS developers I found this solution: add a UIScrollView element to the main view and add the UICollectionView as an element of the UIScrollView. Then create a zoom delegate for the UIScrollView.

```
MainScrollView = new UIScrollView(new CGRect(View.Frame.X, View.Frame.Y, size.Width, size.Height));

        
        _cellReuseId = GenCellReuseId();

        _contentScroll = new UICollectionView(new CGRect(View.Frame.X, View.Frame.Y, size.Width, size.Height), new InfiniteScrollCollectionLayout(size.Width, size.Height));
        
        _contentScroll.AllowsSelection = true;
        _contentScroll.ReloadData();


        _contentScroll.Center = MainScrollView.Center;
        _contentScroll.Frame = new CGRect(_contentScroll.Frame.X, _contentScroll.Frame.Y - 32, _contentScroll.Frame.Width, _contentScroll.Frame.Height);
        MainScrollView.ContentSize = _contentScroll.ContentSize;
        MainScrollView.AddSubview(_contentScroll);
        MainScrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 4f;
        MainScrollView.MinimumZoomScale = 1f;
        MainScrollView.BouncesZoom = true;
        MainScrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) =>
        {
            if (_contentScroll.Frame.Height < sv.Frame.Height && _contentScroll.Frame.Width < sv.Frame.Width)
            {
                _contentScroll.Center = MainScrollView.Center;
                _contentScroll.Frame = new CGRect(_contentScroll.Frame.X, _contentScroll.Frame.Y - 64, _contentScroll.Frame.Width, _contentScroll.Frame.Height);
                _contentScroll.BouncesZoom = true;
                _contentScroll.AlwaysBounceHorizontal = false;
            }
            return _contentScroll;
};
```