# UIImageView inside a scrollView with screen rotation

Tags: objective-c

Its been 2 days working on this problem and i just can't figure it out.

I have a `UIScrollView` stretched in all my view and i am adding to it as subViews a random number of `UIImageView`s, and i am enabling paging so it will look like a gallery app.

My problem is when i rotate the screen, the images frames stays the same (this is probably because of the constraints) so i tried to give the images constraints and it worked they would rotate perfectly but then a problem appeared where the scroll view wont scroll anymore and the images are on top of each other ..

This is my code :

```
-(void)setupScrollView
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < [_arrayOfImages count] ; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*i, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [imageView setImage:[[_arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:i] getImageForImageView:imageView]];
        [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

        [imageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        [_scrollView addSubview:imageView];

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];
    }
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*[_arrayOfImages count], self.view.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Can anyone help me please ? thanks

Comment: Is there a special reason why don't you use     UICollectionView ?

Comment: i need to add zoom on image .. can i do that with `UICollectionView` ? @SabricanOzan

Comment: I think it depends on what gesture you are gonna use. There is a thread about zooming in here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485617/make-uicollectionview-zoomable  you can get some ideas :)

Comment: All you constrains is related to self.view. If you would like to make gallery, constrains should be related from one image to another.

Comment: i think i get your point .. and how can i do that ? any example .. @AndreySapunov

Comment: You can try to create an NSMutableArray, add pointer to each UIImageView to this array, and for all imageView's after first change toItem:self.view to toItem:[imageViewArray objectAtIndex:i-1]

Comment: please can you write me an answer ? thanks i really appreciate it @AndreySapunov

Comment: " images are on top of each other .." what does it mean?

Comment: they all have the same position .. @anhtu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the frame of UIScrollView and the UIImageViews in Autorotate delegate methods. After that you have to change the ContentSize of UIScrollView.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientat‌​ion{}
  //ios 7
   -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrient‌​ation{}
   duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration -
   -(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOri‌​entation{}
   //ios 8 
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
   withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator{
   if (size.width > size.height) { 
      // Positions for Landscape 
   } else {
     // Positions for Portrait 
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you ! gonna try this but i think this is what i needed thank you

Comment: You are welcome :). I had the same problem and this is the way I fixed it, hope you'll make it.

Comment: it actually did .. Thanks a lot ! no need for constraints

Answer (score 0):

I'am not really sure, because I need to see all application, but you can try following code

```
-(void)setupScrollView
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < [_arrayOfImages count] ; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*i, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [imageView setImage:[[_arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:i] getImageForImageView:imageView]];
        [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

        [imageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        [_scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageViewArray addObject:imageView]

        if (i == 0) {
            [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];
            [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];
            [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];
            [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];
        } else {
            UIImageView * previousView = [imageViewArray objectAtIndex:i-1];

            [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];
            [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];
            [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];
            [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:previousView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];
        }
    }

    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*[_arrayOfImages count], self.view.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Also, you need to declare `imageViewArray` as `NSMutableArray`:

add to `@interface`:

```
NSMutableArray * imageViewArray;
```

and in viewDidLoad:

```
imageViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: You shouldn't relate all 4 constraints to the previous item. Depending if the gallery is horizontal or vertical, either top/bottom should be related to the container or the leading/trailing.

Comment: Also you should change constraints on the view's width/height after rotation

Comment: can you guide me and show me how ? its driving me crazy @Alistra