# Loading only visible content on correct position inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage

I have a UIScrollView in which I want to add a huge amount of subviews. Every picture is 256x256 pixels. The ContentSize of the ScrollView is 8.192 pixels, so this would be 32x32 images. I want to only load the UIImages / create the UIImagesViews I am currently seeing. I probably have to use scrollViewDidScroll and determine the correct position of that image via contentOffset. 
The Images are on a server and I load them asynchronously. The folder structure is "Images/Row/Column/row_column.jpg" Where Row and Column will be replaced by the actual number e.g. "Images/4/2/4_2.jpg"

I want to stick with UIScrollView, because it gives me more possibilities than a UICollectionView.

I hope you can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: `UICollectionView` + [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) should achieve what you want.

Comment: I Need zooming, so that's no option

Comment: Seems that `UICollectionView` can support zoom http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485617/make-uicollectionview-zoomable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a complete custom framework for my use case, which caches, and loads only the images I need.

I did not use a UICollectionView as supposed by josefdlange

Thank You for your help.

Comment: Share your solution so that the rest of us can learn.

Answer (score 1):

I think the direction you may want to look is implementing a `UICollectionView` with a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` that responds to pinch-to-zoom gestures. That's the hard part. Then the easy part is implementing your datasource, which `UICollectionView` uses for lazy-loading of its cells (your images).

I haven't watched this video but a quick Google search pointed me to it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vB2TMS2uhE

Comment: Then again if you're expecting it to work more like a wall of pictures you can zoom in and out of perhaps it's not the best solution. You could probably think about the patterns that `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` implement -- data source and delegation -- to figure out a way that you lazily load your image views using `scrollViewDidScroll`

Comment: The Problem is that I want to add way more functionality like panning, turning, zooming, scrolling. Essentially it is going to be a fictional map. With navigational functions

Comment: See my comment and look into the design of `UITableViewDelegate`/`UITableViewDataSource` -- the patterns they follow are probably where you'll want to start. A table view is a subclass of a scrollview and essentially observes changes in the scrolling to determine which views it should ask its data source for and to paint in the content view.