# Zoom UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am using UICollectionView with flow layout. What i want is to achieve zoom in and zoom out like we zoom image. I don't want to zoom in particular cell but the entire UICollectionView.

I have tried nesting UICollectionView inside UIScrollView and used it's delegates to zoom UICollectionView. But It causing scrolling conflict between ScrollView and UICollectionView.

I want to zoom whole UICollectionView. Not the particular cell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make UICollectionView zoomable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485617/make-uicollectionview-zoomable)

Comment: @MarcosGriselli That is used for zooming particular UICollectionViewCell not the entire UICollectionView

Comment: `UICollectionView` already is `UIScrollView`. Why should you wrap it?

Comment: @Sulthan Because UIScrollView provides inbuilt zoom to its subviews. So to zoom entire UICollectionView, i wrapped it inside UIScrollView. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html

Comment: @AkshayYaduvanshi Can U share screenshot of your output, So i can answer according to it